# Apply two query statments to a list of tables in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my sqlite database I dynamically generate several (~150) tables, each representing a dataset consisting of a time stamp and a floating point value. These tables can each be described or generated by the following statement:

```
create table "MY_FIRST_TABLE"
(
    Date  TIMESTAMP,
    Value REAL
);

create index "ix_MY_FIRST_TABLE_Date"
    on "MY_FIRST_TABLE" (Date);
```

Now I want to create a query to retrieve for every one of the tables the first and last date that has a valid value (not equal to None).

I have already found out that I can query a list of all tables in my database with the following statement:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    sqlite_schema
WHERE
    type ='table' AND
    name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';
```

In addition, I have the two commands to query for each of the first and last date that has a valid value (not equal to None):

```
SELECT Date
FROM "MY_FIRST_TABLE"
WHERE Value is not null
ORDER BY Date ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT Date
FROM "MY_FIRST_TABLE"
WHERE Value is not null
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Now my question is, how can I merge these three individual queries into a single statement to eventually get a table that contains the name of each table with their first and last date of valid values (not equal to None) as a result, like this:

| Table | First | Last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FIRST_TABLE_NAME | 01.01.2011 | 12.01.2021 |
| SECOND_TABLE_NAME | 05.01.2011 | 05.02.2021 |
| THIRD_TABLE_NAME | 01.06.2011 | 08.11.2021 |

Comment: SQLite does not support dynamic sql so you can't merge all 3 queries. You can merge the last 2 to a single query, but you will have to hardcode the table's name and run it 150 times for each of the tables. The best option is to write the code in a programming language that constructs the sql statement.

Comment: @forpas So how can I combine these two queries to get at least the first and the last date together? I will solve the remainder then using program code.

Comment: Check the query in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the last 2 queries if you use aggregation:

```
SELECT 'MY_FIRST_TABLE' TableName,
       MIN(Date) First,
       MAX(Date) Last
FROM "MY_FIRST_TABLE"
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL;
```

Then use a programming language to construct the sql statement (with `UNION ALL`) with a loop over the tables that you get from the 1st query.

Or, with SQLite, you can get the sql statement with:

```
WITH tables AS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table')
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
         'SELECT ''' || name || 
         ''' TableName, MIN(Date) First, MAX(Date) Last FROM "' || name || '" ' ||
         'WHERE Value IS NOT NULL',
         ' UNION ALL '
       ) sql  
FROM tables;
```

This returns a string like:

```
SELECT 'MY_FIRST_TABLE' TableName, MIN(Date) First, MAX(Date) Last FROM "MY_FIRST_TABLE" WHERE Value IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MY_SECOND_TABLE' TableName, MIN(Date) First, MAX(Date) Last FROM "MY_SECOND_TABLE" WHERE Value IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MY_THIRD_TABLE' TableName, MIN(Date) First, MAX(Date) Last FROM "MY_THIRD_TABLE" WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
```